# How to setup Fiddler and Genymotion?

Tags: emulation, fiddler, genymotion

I just installed fiddler and I'm developing an app in Eclipse and I am using Genymotion to check if this app works or not. How do I setup fiddler correctly to work with Genymotion?

Answer (score 42):

https://cloud.genymotion.com/page/faq/#android-proxy

In your virtual device,

1. Go to Android settings menu
2. In Wireless & Networks section, select Wi-Fi
3. Press and hold for 2 seconds WiredSSID network in the list
4. Choose Modify Network
5. Check Show advanced options
6. Select Manual for Proxy settings menu entry
7. Enter the proxy address: the Fiddler-running PC's `IPAddress` and Port `8888`
8. Press the Save button

In Fiddler,

1. Click Tools menu > Fiddler Options > Connections
2. Tick the `Allow Remote Computers to connect` box
3. Restart Fiddler.

Comment: This is right, but leaves out configuring Fiddler for the proxy.  In Fiddler, you need to go to Tools -> Fiddler Options -> Connections tab -> check "Allow remote computers to connect."  You can also change the port from 8888 to something else on this tab.

Comment: Fair point; whether you need to tick the "Allow remote" option depends on how the emulator does its networking.

Comment: Note that, turn on and off Android Wifi toggle after setup the proxy.

Comment: In my case it worked with the "ip" tied to "adapter Ethernet VirtualBox Host-Only Network".

Comment: In the Genymotion emulator, in Wifi settings, set the hostname = 10.0.3.2 and port = 8888 if you are using Genymotion and fiddler on Windows 7

Comment: Ok, I bookmarked this page because of this great answer!

Answer (score 0):

It is out of context but If you want to get the http and https request response fetch,
use mitmproxy, Really easy

http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/install.html