# How to trace POST data in Genymotion + Fiddler

Tags: android, fiddler, genymotion

I followed this tutorial and was in making Fiddler + Genymotion work https://stackoverflow.com/a/21562678/2098493

However, I can't see my post data in WebForms tab even though I'm passing "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" as content-type (verified via tracing the request headers in my server).

The WebForms tab states that

`Content-Type is ''; this inspector supports x-www-form-urlencoded only`

Are there additional steps for it to trace post data?

Thanks a lot.